# WAV format Not working in HTML5

Tags: html

The WAV format html5 does not work in the single audio tag. I have not tried to convert it to mp3 for what I have to do for it. I did not try to translate it to ogg.

```
<audio controls>
    <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/">
    <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Comment: What does this have to do with ASP.NET?

Answer (score 1):

To play a wav file you would use the audio/wav type.
So, adding a tag like this:

```
<source src="horse.wav" type="audio/wav">
```

However, .wav files don't work natively in IE.
See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats

If you tried the above tag, and it isn't working in a non-IE browser, you may also have to set a mime-type on your web server to stream it.